# SnipCart 2x How to add Stock quantity to product automatically on fetch?

Tags: html, e-commerce, snipcart

I'm using SnipCart 2 and have all my products on one page. Using the Fetch tool in the Snipcart dashboard allows me to gather all products for the inventory. The stock number states Unspecified. How can I code my buy buttons to automatically tell Snipcart the initial stock quantity so I don't have to manually enter it for all products?

```
                <div class="snipcart-add-item"
                    data-item-id="ProductID"
                    data-item-max-quantity="1"
                    data-item-name="Title"
                    data-item-price="40"
                    data-item-url="LINK"
                    data-item-description="Content"
                    data-item-image="IMAGE URL">
                    BUY ME
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The stock count cannot be set on the DOM attributes, however, you can [fetch from a JSON document](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/order-validation#fetching-products-from-a-json-document).

The fetched json document can either contain a single product definition or an array of products. For your example button:

```
{
  "id": "ProductID",
  "name":  "Title",
  "url": "LINK",
  "price": 40,
  "image": "IMAGE URL",
  "inventoryManagementMethod":  "Single",
  "stock": 5,
  "allowOutOfStockPurchases": true
}
```